# See when a mysql read slave was last modified

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to see when the last byte of data was copied over from the master to the slave? Currently to check how 'current' the data is I'm doing some pretty crude such as:

```
select max(last_updated) from one-my-my-tables
```

But it doesn't work too well. Is there a more formal way to do this?

Comment: [`SHOW SLAVE STATUS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-slave-status.html)

Comment: @Barmar where do you run this? When I run in the read-only client I get the following permissions error: `Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER, REPLICATION CLIENT privilege(s) for this operation`.

Comment: @Barmar which field tells me when it was last modified? If you could add that in an answer I could accept that.

Comment: You have to run it from a privileged account, like `root`.

Comment: The `Seconds_Behind_Master` field tells you how up to date the slave is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a privileged MySQL account (e.g. `root`) use:

```
mysql> show slave status;
```

The field:

```
Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
```

tells you how far out of date the slave is.

Comment: thanks -- is there a sql query you can use to just get that one field?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to get the information from `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` without using that statement. I searched for this recently and learned that there are [replication info tables in the PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-replication-tables.html), however none of them contain the `Seconds_Behind_Master`.

Strictly speaking, the `Seconds_Behind_Master` doesn't tell you what you asked, anyway. You asked "when the last byte of data was copied over from the master to the replica?" `Seconds_Behind_Master` tells you the difference between the system time on the replica vs. the timestamp of the last executed event from the relay log.
Or if the replica has executed all downloaded events, it reports 0.

But suppose the replica has lost contact with its master, and there are more logs sitting around on the master waiting to be downloaded? The replica doesn't report this, because it has no idea there are more logs.

A more accurate way of measuring replication lag is to use the [`pt-heartbeat`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-heartbeat.html) script, which is included in the free [Percona Toolkit](https://www.percona.com/software/database-tools/percona-toolkit).

You execute the script on the master, and it inserts a timestamp to a table once per second, like a heartbeat.

Then on the replica you can query the timestamp and compare it to the system time.

- If the replica is caught up, the difference will be zero.
- If the replica has downloaded all the logs, but executing events is lagging, the timestamp difference will show this.
- If the replica has lost contact with its master and hasn't downloaded all the logs, but we know the heartbeat timestamp *should* update once per second, then you can still get an accurate measure of the replication lag.

Comment: oh that's great, thanks for the suggestion. This is more what I'm looking for. Does the percona toollkit work with the normal community editions of mysql? Or do I need to use a percona version of mysql?